# Pharmaceutical Parallel Imports

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset with parallel imports in pharmaceutical containing countries, countries in their basket, drugs, their prices, reference prices (not necessary). Even some of these fields would do.

Comment: What are *countries in their basket*?

Comment: Hi Jan, Could be any countries in Europe, or South Africa, Asia or Middle East, ISA and Canada, which have external reference price. So countries don’t important. Thanks.